# Android speech recognition has a very short timeout when the speaker pauses

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using flutter for one app and i am using speech recognition also.I know u will say open this topic on flutter but this problem is about android . So if i use speech recognition on ios side it has no problem . but if i use speech recognition on android side it has very low duration. For example i am speaking 2-3 seconds and it is closing after that instantly. Can anyone give advice for fix that ?

Fixing that problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwzcT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error speech timeout generally means that you haven't spoken anything or the timeout has occurred without any speech. This plugin is generally for doing speech recognition for short interval of time. If there is silence for (let's say 3 seconds) then it automatically exits because there hasn't been any speech spoken. That's what speech timeout means.

From it's docs in troubleshooting section:

Speech recognition stops after a brief pause on Android

```
Android speech recognition has a very short timeout when the
speaker pauses. The duration seems to vary by device and
version of the Android OS. In the devices I've used none have 
had a pause longer than 5 seconds. Unfortunately there 
appears to be no way to change that behaviour.
```

Also this plugin is for short term recognition not continuous recognition

From it's docs

```
There have been a number of questions about how to 
achieve continuous speech recognition using this plugin. 
Currently the plugin is designed for short intermittent 
use, like when expecting a response to a question, or 
issuing a single voice command. Issue #63 is the current 
home for that discussion. There is not yet a way to 
achieve this goal using the Android or iOS speech 
recognition capabilities.
```

For more information see: [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text)

Comment: yes i read that already. do u know any way to fix that ?